# Force unmount of usb drive by closing open applications programatically

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, mount, udev

When I unplug the AC adapter from my laptop I want all USB drives to automatically unmount. If applications are open that block the device, they should be killed. Once everything is killed and unmount a signal tone could be plaid to indicate that it's now safe to unplug it.

The use case is to quickly grab and go your laptop without having to fumble with the ui to get all drives disconnected but avoid unclean unmounts.

Any hints on how to start would be fantastic, thanks you!

**ANSWER**

> For a full copy&paste script see my answer below.

---

If your USB devices mount to /mount/media do:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t $(mount | grep "/mount/media" | cut -d " " -f 1)) # Exit processes blocking umount cleanly
kill $(lsof -t $(mount | grep "/mount/media" | cut -d " " -f 1)) # Force kill remaining open processes
umount $(mount | grep "/mount/media" | cut -d " " -f 1) # Unmount USB drives
```

Be careful with this since if you don't have blocking applications open `lsof` will return all `pids` and you will `kill` your running OS. See the copy&paste script below for a working implementation that handles this case.

Then call this script whenever the AC adapter is unplugged by adding this line to `/etc/udev/rules.d`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="change", ATTR{online}=="0" ,     RUN+="/path/to/script/shown/above"
```

The answer below by Nuetrino shows how to detect the AC unplug event, this answer:  [How do I find out which process is preventing a umount?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11713/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-preventing-a-umount) shows how to list and kill all processes blocking the device from unmounting (I had more success with lsof than fuser -c which sometimes didn't list any processes even though umount was still being blocked)

**Details**

Use `udevadm monitor` to log the event, e.g.

```
KERNEL[20154.545075] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP0 (power_supply)
```

then use `udevadm info -a -p` with the event to get the attributes

```
udevadm info -a -p /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP0
    looking at device '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP0':
        KERNEL=="ADP0"
        SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply"
        DRIVER==""
        ATTR{online}=="0"
        ATTR{type}=="Mains"
```

Now you can set up the udev rules with the attributes you like as answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step by step solution**

1.
Create this script e.g. in `/home/user/uall.sh` and replace `mount_root` with the folder where your distribution mounts usb drives, e.g. `/media/user`

```
#!/bin/bash
mount_root=/run/media/user

echo "Try unmounting.."
umount $(ls -d -1 $mount_root/*) # Unmount USB drives
mounted=$(ls -d -1 $mount_root/*) # Probe if there are still applications blocking
if ! [ -z "$mounted" ]
then
    echo "Found blocked devices: $mounted, killing.."
    kill -9 $(lsof -t $mounted) # Exit processes blocking umount cleanly
    kill $(lsof -t $mounted) # Force kill remaining open processes
    echo "Unmounting.."
    umount $(ls -d -1 $mount_root/*) # Unmount USB drives
    mounted=$(ls -d -1 $mount_root/*) # Probe if there are still applications blocking
fi

if [ -z "$mounted" ]
then
    echo "Success!"
    echo "All USB devices umount."
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/speech-dispatcher/test.wav
else
    echo "Error!"
    echo "Tried it all but couldn't umount all USB devices."
    echo "These devices are still mounted:"
    echo "$mounted"
fi
```

2.
Create a udev wrapper script (call it `/home/user/uall-udev-wrapper`) that executes `uall.sh` as your username:

```
#!/bin/bash
runuser -l <user> -c '/home/user/uall.sh > /home/user/uall.log'
```

3.
Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-unmount.rules` with the content

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="change", ATTR{online}=="0" ,     RUN+="/home/user/uall-udev-wrapper"
```

4.
Reboot or run `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` to load the new udev rule

Optional. Add an `alias uall=/home/user/uall.sh` to your `~/.bashrc` to access the script easily from your terminal and use your Desktop environment to configure a hotkey to quickly unmount all usb drives

**Caveats**

1.
When udev runs the script `mount` will not display `gvfsd-fuse` mount points, neither will `cat /proc/mounts` or `cat /etc/mtab` not even if using the `runuser -l <user>` wrapper. Instead I'm using now `ls -d -1 $mount_root/*` which only returns the devices mounted by the current user specified in `$mount_root`, on a multi user system devices mounted by a different user will not be unmounted by this script.

2.
When udev runs the script I do not get audio from `paplay` or `spd-say`.

Any input on these caveats would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be a new question to get more responses

Comment: why the downvotes? this script is awesome, I use it every day, if down voting please state why ..

Answer (score 3):

You can define udev rules to do it.

Just put your rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d`

Here is a example from me which i use to control brightness when i remove the AC adapter.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="change", ATTR{online}=="0" , RUN+="/usr/local/bin/bright_unplug"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="change", ATTR{online}=="1" , RUN+="/usr/local/bin/bright_replug
```

I run my custom script 'bright_replug' and 'bright_unplug'  when I recieve kernel uvent.

You can use `udevadm monitor` to

> monitor will print the received events for: UDEV - the event which
>   udev sends out after rule processing KERNEL - the kernel uevent

You can use `udevadm info` to match more attributes

Comment: perfect, thank you very much! @Trevor I don't understand why it you removed the linux tag since this is very obviously happening on linux and why the downvote? If I can understand the reason why I can ask better questions in the future and choose the correct tags, thank you!

Comment: my scripts runs great when launched manually in the terminal, both as user and root, but if udev calls it `journalctl` reports it exited with code 1, I can `touch` files and they get created but nothing is being unmount or killed, how can I debug this, what could be the issue?

Comment: when udev calls `moun` it does not display `gvfsd-fuse` mount points, so a workaround is to use `ls -d -1 /mound/media` instead unless someone finds out how to list all user mountpoints, even using `runuser -l user` or `cat /proc/mounts` don't display the user mounts